# How can I load external properties file in angular 8?

Tags: angular, weblogic, war

I have a project in Angular 8 where I use const to load properties in my project
[image: my project constants]
Now I'm required to load these properties outside of this project, it could be in a json/properties file.

The problem is when I deploy this angular project into weblogic, because I copied all my dist folder and packaged this into a .war file so this means that this properties/json file should be outside of the .war file.

Is there a way I can load these config files from my filesystem server?

Answer (score 0):

Unlike to server app deployment, client app (Angular app) deployment won't work the same way. In my view, couple of options for you now -

1. Keep your config JSON file in static public hosted folder of weblogic (if weblogic configured to act as static webserver as well)
2. Host your JSON to absolutely outside of app server, may public some storage bucket/file server backed by CDN.

Then access the file using fetch/XHR.

On other note, if you are NOT doing any server side rendering using Java with Angular, you may consider deploying your app (dist folder) to simple web servers like Apache or Firebase hosting. In this way you can host you JSON as well in same environment.

Hope this helps!